# How to add the Table Name of the changed record along with typical AuditTrail in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, audit-trail, changelog

I am using Audit Trail which works great.  The code I have is:

```
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctl As Control
Dim datTimeCheck As Date
Dim strUserID As String
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
datTimeCheck = Now()
strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")
Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        ![UserName] = strUserID
                        ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                        ![Action] = UserAction
                        ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next ctl
    Case Else
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
            ![UserName] = strUserID
            ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
            ![Action] = UserAction
            ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
            .Update
        End With
End Select
AuditChanges_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

The only issue I have is that I have several tables all of which are using autonumbers as primary keys.  Audit trail logs the same RecordID for both my CompanyT and my EmployeeT; for example, and I can't differentiate which was updated.  I need to log the actual table name where the RecordID was sourced.  In other words if RecordID 123 was updated, I want Audit Trail to tell me that was a primary key from EmployeeT table.

How could I tweak the code above to capture the table name?

Comment: But doesn't *FormName* tell you the table source of *RecordID*?

Comment: Form name isn't necessarily same as table name. Add another argument to the function. Pass the table name to the function.

Comment: Somewhere must be calling the given function in the first place, AND that call must be specifying the IDField.  Why not pass in the source table and/or form to this function?  In other words, if one must seed this function with explicit information, then why not go ahead and give it other explicit data rather than complicate the function by having it look up information which is probably already known when the function is called?

Comment: The FormName uses a record located in a table.  I just need to know the name of that table.  I think June and Perkins were commenting on exactly what I need to do.  I just don't know how to do it.  I don't know enough about VBA coding to add the table name the records are originating from to the AuditTrail's table.

Comment: Search through all of the form code to find instances of where `AuditChanges()` is being called.  If you aren't familiar enough with Access and VBA to read the code and figure out where the data is coming from, it will be difficult to explain more details.  Maybe ComputerVersteher's answer will be sufficient.  Otherwise, update the question with an example of the code which calls `AuditChanges()` once you find it. (Also, click the help link to the right of the comment box to learn how to notify others to whom you are responding.  Otherwise they will not be actively notified of your responses.)

Answer (score 0):

You can [Get the Source Table of a Bound Control](http://datagnostics.com/dtips/boundcontrol.html) with

```vb
ctl.Parent.Recordset.Fields(ctl.ControlSource).SourceTable
```

OldValue/NewValue are memo-fields? If not take care of auditlng memo-fields.

What about subform controls?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm not sure where to put your code into my code in order to give me a new column called "TableName".  Please elaborate.

Comment: You must **manually add** a new column to the table [tblAuditTrail].  You do this within Access table designer.  The code itself will not create your new column--it expects it to be there already.  Then follow the pattern in the code to insert the value suggested by ComputerVersteher.

Comment: Sorry, I knew that, I just didn't explain it very well.  I have already added a column in the AuditTrailT called "TableName".  I just don't know how to get it to populate with data.

Answer (score 0):

Perkins,

I couldn't find that link on how to tag you.  I hope you get this or someone else can assist me.  Understand now what you meant by your question about a code calling something.  I believe this is what was missing:

Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
If Status = acDeleteOK Then Call AuditChanges("ProjectID", "DELETE")

End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord Then
    Call AuditChanges("ProjectID", "NEW")
Else
    Call AuditChanges("ProjectID", "EDIT")
End If
End Sub
```

That is code placed in each form where I want to track changes.  The changes are tracked only on controls where I added "Audit" to the Tag property.  Any change to those controls uses the calls above to utilize the module I first posted that then writes data to my AuditTableT.

It just doesn't write enough data...  I also want it to write the TableName where the data is from, not just the FormName, and data changes.  I have no idea what to do with the code Versteher typed.  Would that go in the module or in the call coding I posted in this reply?